# How accelerate reduce and forEach method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, numbers, closures

I wrote a program to count sum of range of array items, but still can not pass the quiz because my code is slow: `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`. How can I speed up my code to [pass the quiz](https://www.codewars.com/kata/583d171f28a0c04b7c00009c/train/javascript)?

```js
function maxSum(arr, range) {
  let result = -Infinity
  range.forEach(el => {
    let sumArr = arr.slice(el[0],el[1]+1).reduce((a,b) => a+b)
    sumArr > result && (result = sumArr)
  })
  console.log(result)
return result 
}
maxSum([1,-2,3,4,-5,-4,3,2,1],[[0,8],[1,3],[0,4],[6,8]])
```

Comment: Your snippets takes some milliseconds. So... If you want help with the _"12000 ms"_ code than post it...

Comment: `arr.slice` creates a copy of the array so maybe you don't want to do that.

Comment: I think one method to speed it up **may** be to remove subsets from the equation. For example, all [1,3], [0,4] and [6,8] are in [0,8]. Therefore sum [0,8] is maximum and you only need to calculate it.

Comment: Felix Kling  Looking strange ...

Comment: Ambu , there is a negative numbers ...

Comment: @Quintis True, my bad.

Comment: Felix Kling and what analog of arr.slice can I use in this situatuion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a faster and simpler solution. Iterates over `range` just once and collects all the sum totals, then maps it into sum ranges, then returns the max:

```js
function maxSum(arr, range) {
  let left = [0];
  let total = 0;
  
  for (let num of arr) {
    left.push(total += num);
  }

  let sums = range.map(([a, b]) => left[b + 1] - left[a]);
  
  let result = Math.max(...sums);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

maxSum([1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1], [[0, 8], [1, 3], [0, 4], [6, 8]]);
```

Comment: map(([a, b]) => left[b + 1] - left[a]) - interesting use case

Comment: pretzelhammer , please  , can you show detailed description of this function ?

Comment: precalculate sum(0...n) for n=[0...length],  return sum(0...n1) - sum(0..n2) = sum(n1..n2)